# How I need to return the value from "operator->()" in this case? "const" or "non-const"?

Tags: c++11, constants

If I want to implement `operator->()` for class of iterator (non-const), what is the correct way for returning the value?
`const T*` or `T*` ? (while `T` is the type of any element in my array..)

Comment: If `operator*` returns `const T&`, then `operator->` returns `const T*`. If `operator*` returns `T&`, then `operator->` returns `T*`, no?

Comment: @DeiDei Why are you think so?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Where are you see there answer for my qeustion?

Comment: @MathQues: The first answer to that question has the code you need.